# Trigger automaticamente bloqueia a tabela (LOCK TABLE)?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Sobre **TRIGGER** em uma tabela qualquer:

- A **TRIGGER bloqueia (LOCK) a tabela** até o fim de sua execução?

  - Caso não, **quando devo** bloqueá-la?
  - **Como faço** esse bloqueio?

Comment: Se esta usando "COMMIT e ROLLBACK", sim.. Dentro do BeginTransation você consegue fazer com que sua tabela fique bloqueada esperando terminar toda sua transação,

Comment: @DanielleArrudatorres Então se eu não estiver usando `COMMIT e ROLLBACK`, e não forçar o `LOCK`, então não trava?

Comment: A trigger se caracteriza por ser um contador onde o problema de concorrência é perfeitamente administrável. Com base nela, não seria teoricamente possível que dois usuários concorrentes conseguissem o mesmo valor dela.

Comment: Não entendi sua resposta, pois dá-se a entender que é possível, e depois não. De qualquer forma vou explicar melhor o porque da dúvida: Tenho um sistema ERP que faz toda manipulação do BD. Então preciso de uma trigger que irá sempre verificar um `UPDATE` em uma tabela, e alterar o registro caso esteja em condição. O problema é que isso intermitentemente causa erros. Por isso a ideia de bloquear a tabela enquanto se executa a trigger. Mas isso é somente uma suposição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim existe o lock até a transicao terminar.

> Os gatilhos funcionam em transações (implícitas ou não) e, enquanto
>   estiverem abertos, bloquearão recursos. O bloqueio permanecerá em
>   vigor até que a transação seja confirmada (com COMMIT) ou rejeitada
>   (com um ROLLBACK). Quanto mais um gatilho é executado, maior a
>   probabilidade de outro processo ser bloqueado. Portanto, os gatilhos
>   devem ser escritos de maneira a reduzir sua duração sempre que
>   possível.

na [documentacao](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#optimizing-dml-triggers) oficial vc pode ler mais a respeito

Comment: HudsonPH, teria como postar as partes da documentação que diz isso? Assim fica uma resposta completa para pesquisa, e também não há problema do link sair do ar. (além de que poderão sinalizá-la por ser basicamente como um comentário). ✌️

Comment: sim, vou editar agora,

Answer (score -1):

"Triggers são usados para realizar tarefas relacionadas com validações , restrições de acesso , rotinas de segurança e consistência de dados ; desta forma estes controles deixam de ser executados pela aplicação e passam a ser executados pelos Triggers"

Um gatilho é um tipo especial de procedimento armazenado que é executado automaticamente quando um evento ocorre no servidor de banco de dados.

Todas as transações DML (INSERT, UPDATE OU DELETE) no banco de dados seguem um fluxo de transações que não vemos, mas que o gerenciados do banco de dados executa automaticamente:

Se mesmo assim, ainda há duvida sobre como Trigger funciona e se você deseja ter a certeza que a tabela deverá ficar bloqueada a qualquer acesso durante a execução da trigger coloque dentro de um BeginTransation.

Exemplo: Abaixo será disparado quando alguém tentar incluir ou alterar dados na tabela Titles. Ele emite uma mensagem ao usuário. ( 50009 é uma mensagem definida para o usuário em sysmessages.)

```
USE pubs
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
      WHERE name = 'reminder' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER reminder
GO
CREATE TRIGGER reminder
ON titles
FOR INSERT, UPDATE 
AS RAISERROR (50009, 16, 10)
GO
```